# Pass a variable from public void OnCreate

Tags: android, eclipse

I wanted to know how can I pass a variable from private void to OnCreate?

```
public final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            if(D) Log.i(TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                setStatus(getString(R.string.title_connected_to, mConnectedDeviceName));
                mConversationArrayAdapter.clear();
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                setStatus(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_LISTEN:
            case BluetoothChatService.STATE_NONE:
                setStatus(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_WRITE:
            byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the buffer
            String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add("Me:  " + writeMessage);
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ:
            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
            // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

            int k=Integer.parseInt(readMessage.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));
            mConversationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ciao"+k ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            break;
        case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
            // save the connected device's name
            mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to "
                           + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case MESSAGE_TOAST:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString(TOAST),
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

This is OnCreate:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mvc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    mvc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while (progressStatus < 1000) {
                        Random r = new Random();
                        int i1 = r.nextInt(1000);
                        if (i1 > progressStatus){
                            progressStatus = i1;
                        }
                        else {
                            progressStatus = progressStatus;
                        }
                        // Update the progress bar and display the current value in the text view
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);

                            }
                        });
                        try {
                            // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. Just to display the progress slowly
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }
    });
    res = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    res.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressStatus=0;

        }
    });

    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "+++ ON CREATE +++");

    // Set up the window layout

    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    // Get local Bluetooth adapter
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    // If the adapter is null, then Bluetooth is not supported
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
```

I pass the variable **k**, is there a method? or I have to go to a public int? I do not know how to solve. Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is neither a private void nor onCreate in your code. Please try to show us a relevant code snipped, or even better, an abstract sample.

Comment: Where is k?? You aren't being clear about your motive. You want to pass a variable to the onCreate() method from a private method?

Comment: k is an integer variable present in CASE "messagg_read". Yes i want pass a variable in a OnCreate method

Answer (score 0):

Umm, why not make k a Global Variable?

Add `int k` inside starting of your class

For example :

```
... 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

int k;

//onCreate and other methods
}
...
```

Change
`int k = =Integer.parseInt (readMessage.replaceAll.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));`

to

`k = =Integer.parseInt(readMessage.replaceAll.replaceAll("[\\D]",""));` 
as you've already made k an integer.

Then you can use k anywhere in your class